# How do you apply different colors from different css rules to the same object?

Tags: css, less

With the html code:

```
<div class="c1">Color 1</div>
<div class="c2">Color 2</div>
<div class="c1 c2">Mix of color 1 and 2</div>
```

and this css rules:

```
.c1 {
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5)
}
.c2 {
    background-color: rgba(0,255,0,0.5)
}
```

I would like the 3rd div be yellow. (it is green).

I know that it is possible to define another rule for the mix:

```
.c1.c2 {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,0,0.5)    
}
```

But imagine that I have lots of colors, or what it is worst: lots of classes with different rules that can be mixed.

Is there a way to do that in pure CSS without having to define the rules for all possible combinations?

Comment: Short answer, no. Long answer, use a CSS preprocessor to build up all the combinations programmatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do color operations with LESS

Goto http://less2css.org/

Copy this code into the input:

```
@red: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
@green: rgba(0,255,0,0.5);
@yellow: @red + @green;
.test
{
  background-color: @yellow;
}
```

which produces the css output:

```
.test {
  background-color: #ffff00;
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

OK , after your comment and re-reading the question, I tthink this is what you want to do:

LESS:

```
@red: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
@green: rgba(0,255,0,0.5);

.c1
{
  background-color: @red;
}
.c2
{
  background-color: @green;
}

.c1.c2
{
  background-color: @red + @green;
}
```

which produces:

```
.c1 {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.c2 {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
}
.c1.c2 {
  background-color: #ffff00;
}
```

Comment: Great answer!, It's important to note that you only have to define only one variable for each class (in this case C1 and C2). The values for the mixed classes are calculated automaticaly!

Answer (score 0):

No, You have to use separate css for each color.

```
 .c3 { background-color: Yellow;}
```

for third div.